# LINQ IQueryable issue when joining 2 tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using EF pulling data into Angular UI. This EF is code-first mapped and I'm trying to get data from 2 tables Tabl1 and T2 using union. The current code gets data from below code from 1 table

```
var utility = new QueryableUtility<Table1Entity>();

var queryable = utility.findQueryable(
   Request,
   db.Table1.AsQueryable(),
   QueryParamArray.Instance.FSParameterArray,
   new Table1Entity()
);
```

I changed the code to below to get common fields from both tables and use `UNION`

```
var t1 = 
   db
   .Table1
   .Select(x => new Table1Dto {
      Id = x.Id,
      Name = x.Name,
      Status = x.Status
   }).ToList();

var t2 = 
   db
   .Table2
   .Select(x => new Table2Dto {
      Id = x.Id,
      Name = x.Name,
      Status = x.Status
   }).ToList();

var qry = t1.Union(t2);

var utility = new QueryableUtility<Table1Entity>();

var queryable = utility.findQueryable(
   Request,
   qry.AsQueryable(),
   QueryParamArray.Instance.FSParameterArray,
   new Table1Entity()
);
```

In the line `qry.AsQueryable()`, I'm getting below error:

> cannot convert from system.linqIqueriable  to system.linqIqueriable

Comment: What is `QueryableUtility`?

Answer (score 3):

`t1` and `t2` are no longer `IQueryable`s since you have called `.ToList()`. And so neither is `qry`. You call `.AsQueryable()` to get around this, but what you then have is something from LINQ to Objects pretending to be a 'real' `IQueryable` when it isn't. I'm not sure what `QueryableUtility` is, but it probably wants 'real' `IQueryable`s to work with.

The first step would be to remove the `.ToList()` calls and the `.AsQueryable()` call should then also be unnecessary.

From there you may or may not have other query-related errors.

Since you are calling `Union`, the types of the two queries must be the same. You could possibly use anonymous types to be able to merge them:

```
var t1 = 
   db
   .Table1
   .Select(x => new {
      Id = x.Id,
      Name = x.Name,
      Status = x.Status
   });

var t2 = 
   db
   .Table2
   .Select(x => new {
      Id = x.Id,
      Name = x.Name,
      Status = x.Status
   });

var qry = t1.Union(t2);

var utility = new QueryableUtility<Table1Entity>();

var queryable = utility.findQueryable(
   Request,
   qry,
   QueryParamArray.Instance.FSParameterArray,
   new Table1Entity()
);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I tried the below and

Comment: var qry = t1.Union(t2).AsQueryable();

Comment: public IQueriable<T> findQueryable(httpRequestMessage req, IQueriable<T> queryable, QueryParam[] queryArray, T obj)  Need help with casting converting from Table1dto to Table1Entity

Comment: @ShanmugamR Yeah, I guess you are calling `Union` which will require both sets to have the same type. You would have to convert the two different entities into a common type (which you could do since they are being built with the same fields). If you used compatible anonymous types you might be able to keep it in the `IQueryable` realm. I'll update with an example.

Comment: Dave, this is what I modified

Comment: namespace AppApi.Models
[AutoMap(typeof(Table1Entity))]

public class Table1dto
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Status {get; set;}
}

namespace AppApi.Models.Entities
{
public class Table1Entity
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Status {get; set;}
}
}

Comment: var t1 = db.Table1
   .Select(x => new Table1dto{
      Id = x.Id,
   }).AsQueryable();

var t2 = 
   db
   .Table2
   .Select(x => new Table1dto{
      Id = x.Id,
   }).AsQueryable();

var qry = t1.Union(t2).FirstorDefault();

var utility = new QueryableUtility<Table1Entity>();

var queryable = utility.findQueryable(
   Request,
   (IQueriable<Table1Entity>)qry,
   QueryParamArray.Instance.FSParameterArray,
   new Table1Entity()
);
Getting error:
Unable to cast object of type 'AppApi.models.Table1dto to type Syatem.Linq.iQueriable '1[AppApi.Models.entityes.Table1Entity'

Comment: @ShanmugamR you haven't explained what `QueryableUtility` is. Apparently it wants an `IQueryable<Table1Entity>` which matches its type argument. But I don't think you will be able to construct `Table1dto` at runtime anyway, since EF will want only to create entities. you've not provided enough information about what you're trying to do, all I can do is point out the obvious errors, but I can't tell what the end goal is.

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm new to this project and new to EF as well. Someone wrote this and left and no technical details. What this api wants to do is:  1. Join 2 tables and sort the results by ID and Name 2. What this Queriable function trying to do is gets Iqueriable<TableEntity> and adds lots of where condition like queriable.where 3. Finally with returned queriable result,  return pageresult <TDto>

Comment: return result code is like below: var ordQry = queruiable.provider.createquery<T>(orderbyexpression); var projection = ordQry.skip(skipamount).Take(pagesize).ProjectTo<tDto)(Mapper.Configuration);  var result= await projection.ToListAsync();  return new PageResult<TDto> { Results = result}

Comment: @ShanmugamR are you still getting an error? making both queries use `Table1Dto` is a good guess. `QueryableUtility` will want both types to be the same. I see `FirstOrDefault` in what you posted though, which doesn't seem right. you should just have `var qry = t1.Union(t2);`. if you are still stuck on a error, let me know the error, or you could also try posting another question that lays out that error and the code involved with it.

Comment: Hi David, after executing var t1 = db.Table1 .Select(x => new Table1dto{ Id = x.Id, }).AsQueryable(); getting error “The function evaluation requires all threads to run”

Comment: @ShanmugamR that is not a program error, that's just something you get from the debugger sometimes. it means it can't evaluate the expression while stopped at a breakpoint.

Comment: Dave, this line queryable = utility.findQueryable( Request, (IQueriable<Table1Entity>)qry, QueryParamArray.Instance.FSParameterArray, new Table1Entity() ) is throwing error “Unable to cast object of type “system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery AppApi.Models.Table1Dto’ to type system.Linq.iqueriable AppApi.Models.Entities.Table1 . The parameter issues should be IQueriable<Table1Entity>)qry,

Comment: @ShanmugamR `qry` is an `IQueryable<Table1Dto>`. To work with your `QueryableUtility` it must match type (I'm just guessing since it's not my code). you probably need `var utility = new QueryableUtility<Table1Dto>();`. But that's not guaranteed to work, I can't tell for sure, because you might not be able to create `Dto` types from a query. There's all kinds of things I could try and do if I was there, but I can't do much from SO comments.

Comment: David, sorry for the delayed response. I ha to split many functions and bring each pieces into a new function to make this work and finally it worked. Thanks for all your feedback and that helped me to understand how things work in EF